# Font size changing with orientation

Tags: android, fonts

I have a problem when I launch my Android app on an Acer 7 inches tablet (Android 6.0). Until changing the tablet orientation, the `fontSize` is bigger that it should be. I don't have this problem with other tablet.

At the end of an `onCreateView`, I get resources information with **`getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale`**. With a normal system `fontSize`, it return `1.15` when app is launched and return `1.0` when changing orientation and remain `1.0` after even if I changed orientation again and again. With normal size `font` on the other tablet `fontScale` is always `1.0`.

I don't know where to look to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For font change for tablet UI you create the new layout for tab and set the text size according to the tab UI.

res/layout/main_activity.xml  # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)

res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)

res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml